# Run batch apex test method as standard user

Tags: salesforce, apex

thanks for reading.

I'm trying to write a test method that runs a batch apex to delete cases using a standard user that does not have deleting access, but whenever I run the test I see that the batch runs under my current (admin) user. Am I missing something?

This is my batch code:

```
global with sharing class BatchDelete implements 
Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

// instance member to retain state across transactions
global Integer recordsProcessed = 0;

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(
        'SELECT ID ' +
        'FROM Case '
    );
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Case> scope){
    System.debug('---------BATCH----------');
    System.debug('Current BATCH User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
    System.debug('isAccessible: ' + Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().isDeletable());
    System.debug('------------------------');

    // process each batch of records
    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
    for (Case c1 : scope) {
        cases.add(c1);
    }
    delete cases;
}    

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed. Shazam!');
}   }
```

And my test method code:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
static  void test_readOnlyUser() {

    UserLicense uL =[SELECT Id,LicenseDefinitionKey,Name FROM UserLicense WHERE Name = 'Salesforce'];
    Profile  p = [SELECT Id  FROM Profile WHERE UserLicenseId =: uL.Id  AND UserType = 'Standard'
                  AND PermissionsModifyAllData = false AND PermissionsViewAllData = false limit 1 ];

    User u = new User(
        UserName = 'test-user@test-company.com',
        FirstName = 'Test-First-Name',
        LastName = 'Test-Last-Name',
        Alias = 'test',
        Email = 'test-user@test-company.com',
        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
        LocalesIdKey = 'en_US',
        TimezonesIdKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
        ProfileId = p.Id
    );

    Case c1 = new Case();
    c1.Status = 'New';
    insert c1;

    Test.startTest();

    System.runAs(u) {

        System.debug('---------TEST-----------');
        System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
        System.debug('isAccessible: ' + Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().isDeletable());
        System.debug('------------------------');

        BatchDelete myBatchObject = new BatchDelete();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(myBatchObject);
    }

    Test.stopTest();
} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` inside the `runAs` call.  This is because since the batch process is asynchronous, it can only be guaranteed to have executed at the moment `Test.stopTest()` is invoked.

```
System.runAs(u) {
   Test.startTest();
   //your batch code  
   Test.stopTest();
}
```